# Hadoop Job finishes at map 0% reduce 0%

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, linux-mint

I am trying to learn hadoop. It installed fine on my system. Its located at /usr/local/hadoop and I'm using jdk1.7.0_45 java.

Whenever I try to run the famous wordcount example, it produces the following output:

```
/usr/local/hadoop $ bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.0.4.jar wordcount /user/hduser/gutenberg /user/hduser/gutenberg-output
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

13/10/31 20:03:24 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 3
13/10/31 20:03:24 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
13/10/31 20:03:24 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
13/10/31 20:03:24 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201310311657_0006
13/10/31 20:03:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/10/31 20:03:25 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201310311657_0006
13/10/31 20:03:25 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 0
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? There's nothing desired in the output folder as it should.

Comment: Make sure jobs running at node and you have correct path for Hadoop_HOME

Comment: In the newest Hadoop setup, warning comes saying HADOOP_HOME is deprecated. Its properly set though to /usr/local/hadoop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open 
jobtracker(`http://localhost:50030/jobtracker.jsp`) -> completed job : job_201310311657_0006 -> It will get you to the job details.
Click on Failed Map attempts . (number under Failed Map)-> click on taskId -> Logs 
there you be be able to see the full stack-trace .

Figure out it out .

The job launched the map task are given, so there may be some prob with the i/p file.(guess)

Paste the Log of job for more help .

Answer (score 0):

replace the "HADOOP_HOME" variable with "HADOOP_PREFIX" variable in your .bashrc file

Comment: This will just take care of the deprecation message.